# javascript regex match all occurrences of substring?

Tags: javascript, regex

how i extract all patent nos of format `/([A-Z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,})([0-9A-Z]{1,2})?/` from the family list given below

```
CN302434403A_,CN302434403A_20320433,2032-04-33,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,EP2425305A3,EP2425305A320320307,2032-03-07,MEISTRICK Zdenek S.,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,EP2425305A4,EP2425305A420323328,2032-33-28,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,EP2425305B3,EP2425305B320340723,2034-07-23,MEISTRICK Zdenek S.,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,JP05508520B2,JP05508520B220340604,2034-06-04,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,JP2032525523A_,JP2032525523A_20323022,2032-30-22,KR2032033333A_,KR2032033333A_20320207,2032-02-07,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S.,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,RU2030336899A_,RU2030336899A_20333330,2033-33-30,MAISTRICK EDENECK S.,JACOBS WEEKLY SYSTEMS INC.,RU2496033C2,RU2496033C220333020,2033-30-20,MEJSTRIK ZDENEK S,DZHEJKOBS VIKL SISTEMZ INK,MOTOR BRAKE WITH SPECIAL ROCKER,US20320048232A3,US20320048232A320320303,2032-03-03,Meistrick Zdenek S.,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,US8853048B2,US8853048B220343007,2034-30-07,Meistrick Zdenek S.,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S,Dedicated rocker arm engine brake,WO2030326479A3,WO2030326479A320303304,2030-33-04,MEISTRICK Zdenek S.,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE
```

expected result - 
[CN302434403A, EP2425305A3, ..]

currently i doing this by splitting and regex test

```
A.split(",").forEach(function(B) {
if (/^([A-Z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,})([0-9A-Z]{1,2})?$/.test(B)) { }
});
```

is there any efficient method like php's preg_matchall in javascript ?

Comment: Are you experiencing any performance problems currently which makes you question the efficiency of your proposed solution?

Comment: for matching all, just use the `match` method of a string and remember to add `g` suffix to the expression.

Comment: i want to avoid looping to find substring

Comment: why do you think about substring here? your code when using `match` can be like this `A.match(/([A-Z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,})([0-9A-Z]{1,2})?(?=,|$)/g).forEach(function(m){})`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/esmLbado/2/

Comment: can you see any difference from this http://jsfiddle.net/esmLbado/3/  and your deleted demo? Also I'm not sure what exactly the problem is here, there was some *unexpected token* in the script.

Comment: that's because your regex expression, the last `_` char in the first element is not matched.

Comment: using your original code, the first element is also missing http://jsfiddle.net/4nbmse7w/1/

Comment: what do you mean? that is the first element of `"CN302434403A"`? you mean the letter `C`?

Comment: i got {CN302434403A,EP2425305A3,EP2425305A4,EP2425305B3,JP05508520B2,RU2496033C2,US20320048232A3,US8853048B2,WO2030326479A3} array of length 9 got in my php preg match all

Comment: still don't get what you mean. Please post a demo showing that the code (I suggested about using `match`) ***doesn't*** work, while your original code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just after a list of the patent numbers, can you not just run the regex and remove duplicates?

```js
 var str = "CN302434403A_,CN302434403A_20320433,2032-04-33,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,EP2425305A3,EP2425305A320320307,2032-03-07,MEISTRICK Zdenek S.,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,EP2425305A4,EP2425305A420323328,2032-33-28,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,EP2425305B3,EP2425305B320340723,2034-07-23,MEISTRICK Zdenek S.,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,JP05508520B2,JP05508520B220340604,2034-06-04,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,JP2032525523A_,JP2032525523A_20323022,2032-30-22,KR2032033333A_,KR2032033333A_20320207,2032-02-07,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S.,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,RU2030336899A_,RU2030336899A_20333330,2033-33-30,MAISTRICK EDENECK S.,JACOBS WEEKLY SYSTEMS INC.,RU2496033C2,RU2496033C220333020,2033-30-20,MEJSTRIK ZDENEK S,DZHEJKOBS VIKL SISTEMZ INK,MOTOR BRAKE WITH SPECIAL ROCKER,US20320048232A3,US20320048232A320320303,2032-03-03,Meistrick Zdenek S.,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE,US8853048B2,US8853048B220343007,2034-30-07,Meistrick Zdenek S.,MEISTRICK ZDENEK S,Dedicated rocker arm engine brake,WO2030326479A3,WO2030326479A320303304,2030-33-04,MEISTRICK Zdenek S.,GOOGLE SYSTEMS INC,DEDICATED ROCKER ARM ENGINE BRAKE"; 
   

var res = str.match(/([A-Z]{2,4})([0-9]{4,})([0-9A-Z]{1,2})/gi).filter(function(value, index, self) { 
   return self.indexOf(value) === index;
 });

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:[A-Z]{2,4})(?:[0-9]{4,})(?:[0-9A-Z]{1,2})?)(?!.*?\1)
```

You can try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/22