# JS Match all occurrences of substring in a string

Tags: javascript

I have seen this link but my question is different.
[javascript regex match all occurrences of substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600303/javascript-regex-match-all-occurrences-of-substring)

`match()` function in `JS` can be used to match a substring in a string.

When I run this code, I got output like this.

```js
let s = 'Hello_HaHaHaHackerRank';
let hacker = s.match('HaHa');
console.log(hacker);
console.log(hacker.index);
console.log(hacker.input);
```

Output:

```
["HaHa"]
6
Hello_HaHaHaHackerRank
```

`hacker.index` is giving one first occurrence of the pattern. But the string has three times `HaHa`. One is at `index 6`, another is at `index 8` and another is at `index 10`.

Can anyone please explain, How can I get the occurrences of all substring?

Comment: Just use a while loop - while it returns true, then keep looking and splicing out the substring

Comment: splicing will create new string every time. The cost of this operation is very high since strings are immutable in JS.

Comment: Well just take out the substring you found every time you found one

Comment: @MoritzRoessler  s.match(/HaHa/g) is returning output like [ 'HaHa', 'HaHa' ]. It is not returning index values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` has a *fromIndex* value you can use with a while loop `str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`

```js
let s = 'Hello_HaHaHaHackerRank';
let find = 'HaHa'
let hacker = [];
let i = 0, j=0;
while (~(i = s.indexOf (find,i + find.length))) hacker.push(i);
console.log (hacker)
```

If you want to include all occurences, don't add the length of the word.

`while (~(i = s.indexOf (find,++i))) hacker.push (i)`

Comment: Thanks for Answer. As I have mentioned the comment in Stefano's Answer that hacker array is returning value as [6,10]. But carefully observe that there are 3 occurrences of HaHa in the string. So, hacker should return [6, 8, 10]

Comment: So you want to include duplicates

Comment: Yes All the occurrences even occurrences inside occurrences

Comment: In that case simply replace `i + find.length` by `++i`

Comment: You should probably explain what the tilde does in your answer - for the OP and for other people visiting the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
let re = /HaHa/g,
str = "Hello_HaHaHaHackerRank";
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
  console.log("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but It is returning o/p like [ 'HaHa', 'HaHa', index: 0, input: 'HaHaHaHackerRank' ]
So, I can't get the index of other matches. There is only one index present in output.

Comment: Updated @PrateekAgrawal, take a look now

Comment: Thank but carefully observe that there are 3 occurrences of HaHa in the string at indexes 6, 8, 10

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer breaks on the following edge case:

```
// Current accepted answer
function findOccurrences(needle, haystack) {
    let hacker = [];
    let i = 0, j=0;
    while (~(i = haystack.indexOf (needle,++i))) hacker.push(i);
    return hacker;
}

console.log(
    'should return 3 occurrences when word is shared among matches', 
    JSON.stringify(findOccurrences('HaHa', 'Hello_HaHaHaHackerRank')) === "[6,8,10]") 
        ? 'Pass' 
        : 'Fail';
// WILL PASS

console.log(
    'should return 3 occurrences when needle is in the beginning of haystack', 
    JSON.stringify(findOccurrences('HaHa', 'HaHaHaHackerRank')) === "[0,2,4]") 
        ? 'Pass' 
        : 'Fail';
// WILL NOT PASS
```

One way to fix the implementation is to move the incrementation logic to inside while's callback:

```
function findOccurrences(needle, haystack) {
    let hacker = [];
    let i = 0, j=0;
    while (~(i = haystack.indexOf (needle,i))) { hacker.push(i); ++i; };
    return hacker;
}
```

Now the tests will pass.